# How to redirect one domain to local ip in router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iis

I want all the devices (mobiles via wifi and all machines via lan) connected to my router to access my local site "http://mylocalsite.com" present at one of the local machine (say 192.168.1.100) in IIS.

I want to do that setting in my Linksys X 3000 router. Is this possible?

My goal is to access http://mylocalsite.com site via my mobile (Android or iPhone)

Comment: You need to add a custom hostname mapping in your router. Whether your Linksys can do this I don't know - check the manual.

Answer (score 1):

When you access `http://mylocalsite.com` with a browser, the browser will try to get the IP address through the DNS server. The DNS server would return you Wan IP refering your router Wan IP if you have registered a domain (`mylocalsite.com`) on it. As a result your browser would send a request to your router. So you need to set a Port Map on you router, that means map the 80 port to your `192.168.1.100` server.